# rate difference one word with field of table

Tags: mysql, difference, rate

Suppose you have a table

```
id | title
-----------
1  | ali 
2  | Ali 
3  | alireza
```

Now I want you to say a command word "ali" check the field's title.
And the output of the table was a table that all records should be returned in the table.
Now the results should be like.

```
id |  title  | diff
---------------------
1  | ali     | 100 
2  | Ali     | 97 
3  | alireza | 50
```

Important: only use commands Sql

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
select id, title,
  case title
    when 'ali' then 100
    when 'Ali' then 97
    when 'alireza' then 50
  end case diff
from mytable;
```

Comment: No
Use this command to just one word (Ali) will result
But I need every word
Have a common command for all entries to be written